# Axes will not start at 0 in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bubble-chart

I have just created my first bubble chart in ggplot and, despite trying just about every 'solution' I could find on the internet for the past few hours, I have not been able to force the axes to start at 0. The x and y axes both start at 10 but I would like the axes to start at 0. I have tried using various combination of xlim, ylim, expand_limits, scale_y_continuous and scale_x_continuous with no luck.

Here's the code I use to create the graph:

```
ggplot(mean_diffs, aes(x=sample, y=marked, size = pop_est)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.7) + scale_size(range = c(2, 10), name="Absolute error", breaks = c(5,10,20,40))
```

[image: The graph]

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: paste the output of `dput(mean_diffs)` into the question, [MRE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you tried, but the following seems to work well, assuming your data are all numeric:

```r
ggplot(mean_diffs, aes(x = sample, y = marked, size = pop_est)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) + 
  scale_size(range = c(2, 10), name = "Absolute error", 
             breaks = c(5, 10, 20, 40)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 60), breaks = 0:6 * 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60), breaks = 0:6 * 10)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data set, inferred from plot in question**

```r
mean_diffs <- data.frame(sample = rep(c(10, 30, 50), each = 3),
                         marked = rep(c(10, 30, 50), 3),
                         pop_est = c(30, 20, 10, 40, 20, 3, 30, 7, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very nearly what I had tried before but when looking at your code more closely I came to the realisation that I had been copying and pasting code segments into the brackets for scale_size rather than add the code after all the close brackets. A beginner mistake I suppose!

Comment: @KingBalloonion that's one of the reasons why it's good practice to format your code properly, including new lines for each step in chained procedures such as ggplot. It not only looks nicer, it really does reduce mistakes and makes it easier to debug your code. I made many such errors when starting out!